# WP all import - how to remove decimals from Woocommerce price?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpallimport

I'm really fighting with displaying incorrect prices at almost 6300 products imported from XML feed. All prices are in format like 409.000 €, which means only 409 €. It displays prices in frontend like 409.000,00 which should be 409,00 (or 409). This `{price[1]}` should be formatted.

Comment: Have you already wrote with the plugin developers?

Answer (score 0):

There are php functions you can use, I am no expert but I use str_replace on some values. In your case something like this might work: [str_replace(".000,00",",00",{price[1]})]
You place this on the import field, where you have {price[1]}
But if you search "wp all import php functions" you'll get more info.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

Could try something like this:

```
function wp_all_import_convert_price($price) {
    $price = str_replace(",", ".");
    $price = str_replace(".", ",");
    return $price;
}
```

Use it like this

```
[wp_all_import_convert_price({price[1]})]
```